# How to understand this sentence “internal to the kernel”

Tags: windows, powershell, kernel

When I use "vssadmin" on Windows7's powershell,I capture an error that "Paths that begin with `\\?\GlobalRoot` are internal to the kernel and should not be opened by managed applications".

What's the meaning of "internal to the kernel" and "managed applications"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Internal to the kernel" means that the path at hand should only be accessed by the operating system's [*kernel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)), and not by applications running in the [*user space* a.k.a *userland*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space_and_kernel_space) (regular applications that run outside the kernel).

*[Managed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code) applications* are one kind of user-space applications, in particular those using a [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET) runtime.